# moment value is shown as " undefined" though the moment package is shown under modules

Tags: node.js, npm, momentjs

[image]I have added package to the working folder using command `npm install moment` as described in moment.js docs.The moment package is also visible under node_modules.Yet the value of `moment` is shown as undefined.If any further details required I will add.

```
var moment = require('moment');
 console.log(moment);//shows 'undefined' value
```

Comment: Have you required the package, as in `var moment = require('moment');` ?

Comment: Yes , I did but still it shows `undefined`  value

Comment: Adding your project directory structure maybe helpful

Comment: if node does not the find the package the `require('moment');` should already throw an error..

Comment: everything seems fine with directory, try again with npm install --save moment and see what version is added in your package.json

Comment: this seems odd,why don't you require moment explicitly and see if it works like require('./node_modules/moment');

Comment: are you running server.js? or some other file where is it located?

Comment: @AJS it is showing this error `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./node_modules/moment"` :(

Comment: @AJS but I can see the module under the `node_modules` folder

Comment: @AJS Yes, there is server.js files

Comment: try  **npm list --depth=0** and add the output, and are you in root directory of your project ie.react-hot-boilerplate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108531/discussion-between-sai-ram-and-ajs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that react-hot-boilerlpate uses ES6 syntax. 
So, if you're using `moment` in your `App.js` you should import it like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment'

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(moment());
    return (
      <h1>Hello, world.</h1>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to require moment in your `app.js`

```
var moment = require('moment');
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but I tried with yours already and it still shows 'undefined'

Comment: you can also use moment for global configs e.g  `moment.locale('en-my-settings', {  // customizations. });`

Comment: no , I used `moment` with meteor and I think that doesn't make sense as `format` is a property of moment

Comment: yes you can console log moment object without format. add your project structure if possible